# Registering Custom ``backend://` scheme is not working in CEF

Tags: c++, post, url-scheme, chromium-embedded, postdata

In my [CEF Application](https://github.com/gabyx/ExecutionGraph/blob/3ff8b340d3ae1c87976104f0bbbda4c048e7eb2b/gui/executionGraphGui/cefapp/App.cpp#L85)

I register a custom scheme handler for the scheme `backend://`. As done in [scheme_handler example](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef-project/src/185e8338bfcb36d98f57797078a671c7c239766c/examples/scheme_handler/app_browser_impl.cc?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#app_browser_impl.cc-37)
I [call in every process](https://github.com/gabyx/ExecutionGraph/blob/3ff8b340d3ae1c87976104f0bbbda4c048e7eb2b/gui/executionGraphGui/cefapp/SchemeHandlerHelper.cpp#L62) (Rendere Process and Browser-Process) 
`AddCustomScheme` :

```cpp
void registerCustomSchemes(CefRawPtr<CefSchemeRegistrar> registrar)
    {
        for(auto& scheme : getCustomSchemes()) // "backend" and "client"
        {
            registrar->AddCustomScheme(scheme,
                                       true /* is standart*/,
                                       false /* is local */,
                                       false /* is display_isolated */,
                                       true /* is secure */,
                                       true /* is cors enabled*/,
                                       false /* is_csp_bypassing*/);
        }
    }
```

The `client://` scheme has also a handler installed.

When I dont call `AddCustomScheme` with both `client` and `backend`. The `backend://` handler works (as well as the `client` handler), but I dont receive any post request data (I send some binary data).

When I use the `AddCustomScheme` the scheme handlers for  `client` and `backend`
are no more triggered.

How should I setup the custom handler `backend` such that it receivs post data requests? I also tried to play around with the bools in `AddCustomHandler` which did not help.

**Update: Solution**
**Don't use capital letters in the host name!!**

```cpp
CefRegisterSchemeHandlerFactory("http", "your-host-name", new ... )
```

Comment: I would help you but I would not since you ask questions, get answers, but did not mark answers on your questions.

Comment: you are right, I completely missed that! sorry :-)

Comment: Thank you. What about answers of other professionals?

Comment: checked a lot of question back to 2013 ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I will look at the issue little later, since Friday is a hard time.

Comment: and the HTTP-scheme precisely works for you? Only httpS works for me :(

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting a cross-origin `XmlHttpRequest` (XHR). You need to configure Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS). Look at `CefAddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry`.

`WebKit` does not pass `POST` data to the request for synchronous XHRs executed on non-HTTP schemes. See the `AreMethodAndURLValidForSend()` checks in `XMLHttpRequest::send() in third_party/WebKit/Source/core/XMLHttpRequest.cpp`.

```
bool XMLHttpRequest::AreMethodAndURLValidForSend() {
  return method_ != HTTPNames::GET && method_ != HTTPNames::HEAD &&
         url_.ProtocolIsInHTTPFamily();
}
```

If you need to use XHR `POST` requests you should register your custom handler using the `HTTP` or `HTTPS` protocol. Since this is an intentional `WebKit` design feature it is likely not changed for `CEF3`.

Comment: ok, I will try to register the `http` scheme. I thought its "synchronous XHRs" but I always use async XHRs..., and you are right Iam sending this from "client://" to "backend://". I will see if `http` works. So far I think I tried that. Lets see if I can register "client" and "http" with the corresponding CefAddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry which I added too.

Comment: How exactly do I register useing the http protocol:
`CefRegisterSchemeHandlerFactory("http", "executionGraph", new BackendSchemeHandlerFactory("executionGraph"));` ?

Comment: and then using `CefAddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry("client://", "http", "", true);`

Comment: I registered now `CefRegisterSchemeHandlerFactory("http", "executionGraph", new BackendSchemeHandlerFactory("executiongraph"));`
and the handler gets triggered (CEF doesnt like captial letters in the host name). The post data is however not available in the handler (`nullptr`)...
This is a bit strange

Comment: You saved my life! I search for so long... No capitals in the domain name.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I though it is known thing. Sorry, I did not have a time to help you deeply due to our product soon release.

Comment: Yes: I used: 
`CefRegisterSchemeHandlerFactory("http", "executiongraph", new ... );`
which has NO captial letters, which works =)