# CEF JS loading errors (using custom scheme)

Tags: c++, cross-domain, chromium-embedded

Currently working on a CEF3 C++ project, I encountered an issue which seems pretty stubborn and really slowing the development process down.

Our app is supposed to serve a SPA. I read that the `file://` scheme is not well suited for loading local data into the browser, therefore we proceeded with implementing `CefSchemeHandler`and `CefSchemeHandlerFactory`, which, as of yet, do nothing more than serve us the files for our SPA.

Now to the problem: We specifically want to load React, React-DOM, and Babel as provided here:
    `https://unpkg.com/react@16.3.2/umd/react.production.min.js`
    `https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.3.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js`
    `https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js`
When loading these via a script tag from the CDN, everything works fine. I only get a cross-origin-acess error for our custom app script with mime type `text/babel`. We want to load all of then "offline" via the SchemeHandler however, and this is where the problem arises.
If I load the scripts in windows and return them to the custom domain via the scheme handler, all we get is Syntax error at the beginning of every script. Sometimes for `!`before function, sometimes something else.
Whatever we do it just does not seem to work out.
I've already verified, all the bytes (the whole script) is being loaded into browser so there is no data loss.

**What is the right way of implementing the `CefSchemeHandler` and serving local huge scripts and files to the browser?**

Edit: To become more clear I would like to add that the question mainly asks about the possible causes for getting a syntax error for the exact same scripts served via a CefSchemeHandler in comparison to everything being fine loading them via file:// or through the CDN.

Edit 2: I changed the custom scheme to https:// and the CORS is working now. However I still have a very weird issue with the js loading. Here is a specific example: I load my index.html via https (working). I then load react.js via a relative path (working)
`<script type="application/javascript" src="lib/react.production.min.js"></script>`
Then I want to load react-dom:
`<script type="application/javascript" src="lib/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>`
And I get `[0511/083919.988:INFO:CONSOLE(75)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token", source: https://test/lib/react-dom.production.min.js (75)`.

**Now the weird thing**: If I load the script (react-dom) from `https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.3.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js` (it's the **exact same** script), **everything works!**

Plase help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Registering Custom \`\`backend://\` scheme is not working in CEF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811756/registering-custom-backend-scheme-is-not-working-in-cef)

Comment: @S.M. While this might be an issue I have, the primary focus of the question lies on the syntax errors arising when I load the same script via scheme handler instead from the CDN.